# Proguard migration to Java 11

Tags: java, maven, java-8, proguard, java-11

I am currently using Java 8 and i would like to migrate to java 11 or java 17. As i am using proguard in my java project i am facing an issue during maven build as some libraries which i am using in proguard have been deleted from java 11. Those libraries are:

```
-libraryjars <java.home>/lib/rt.jar
-libraryjars <java.home>/lib/jsse.jar
-libraryjars <java.home>/lib/jce.jar
```

Any suggestion on which libraryjars i should use in order to replicate the same behavior?

Thank you everyone for your time!

Comment: First of all, make sure you are using Proguard 6.1 or later.  Second replace the above with the equivalent stuff in the `<java.home>/jmods` directory.

Comment: Also ... since you are using Maven, take a look at the https://github.com/wvengen/proguard-maven-plugin and https://github.com/wvengen/proguard-maven-plugin/issues/106

Comment: Thank you for the reply I will check it out!

Comment: @StephenC Thank you for your help! In did all i needed was to remove all those jars and replace them with `-libraryjars <java.home>/jmods` . The version i have in my maven-proguard-plugin was already the 6.1.1. Yet again i updated to the latest version.